# C# equivalent to C++ Functor (as a break condition)

Tags: c#

I have the following example code:

```
void Foo()
{   
    while (!_cancelSrc.Token.IsCancellationRequested && currTryNum < maxRetryTimes && !isPublished)
    {
        // do something 
    }
}
```

I want to change the while condition, and pass Foo something equivalent to C++ Functor, that will hold an internal state in order to keep track of currTryNum and isPublish variables. I will define in each what is the maxRetryTimes. something like this:

```
while (!_cancelSrc.Token.IsCancellationRequested && isRequireToContinue())
{
    // do something 
}
```

P.S. It is important to also allow some functor that always returns true, in case I want the while to always run.
tnx!

Comment: An anonymous method that closes around a counter is enough. Then you pass a delegate of this anonymous method to your `Foo` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# you have delegates to pass around methods. You can use an anonymous method that "closes" around a `currTryNum` variable, or you can create a whole class that has `currTryNum` as a property. No difference for the method receiving the delegate (and if you take a look at the generated code, the anonymous method that closes around some variables WILL be converted to an hidden class much like `Tester`)

```
void Foo(Func<bool> predicate)
{   
    while (!_cancelSrc.Token.IsCancellationRequested && predicate())
    {
        // do something 
    }
}
```

Now you could:

```
int currTryNum = 0;
int maxRetryTimes = 1000;
bool isPublished = false;

Foo(() => currTryNum++ < maxRetryTimes && !isPublished);
```

or you could

```
public class Tester
{
    public int CurrTryNum { get; set; } = 0;
    public int MaxRetryTimes = 1000;
    public bool isPublished = false;
    
    public bool Check()
    {
        return currTryNum++ < maxRetryTimes && !isPublished;
    }
}
```

and then

```
var tester = new Tester();
Foo(tester.Check);
```

Comment: I initially was also going to suggest having a static method that returns a delegate: `Func<bool>` and could capture the counter variable; however, that solution wouldn't work with the OP's additional requirement of being able to change the `isPublished` variable from the caller as then you would need to make that a `ref` input and capturing a `ref` variable in a lambda is illegal, so you would have to use a hack and pass it as an array of size 1 or other mutable object.  This makes the solution here the only sensible viable one.